# Execute PowerBi LinEst function for multiple partitions of a table

Tags: powerbi, dax, linear-regression

I want to retrieve the different slopes and intercept outcomes of the Linest function. I'm able to get a single outcome by using the following DAX code:

```
linest_test = LINEST(test[production], test[temp], test[consumption])
```

Outcomes are returned in a calculated table. Using the code above, the whole test table (like below) is used as input for the LinEst function.

I would like to apply the LinEst function on every single day and use the previous 365 days as input. Furthermore I would like to partition this by using the partition_id.

Something like (this is not dynamical):

```
FILTER(
ALL(Table),
Table[Date] >= TODAY() - 365 &&
Table[Date] <= TODAY()
Table[partition_id] = 1
```

)

My input table looks like this:

| partition_id | date | production | temp | consumption | slope 1 | slope 2 | slope 3 | intercept |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20230101 | 1000 | 20 | 150 |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | 20230202 | 1500 | 25 | 200 |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | 20230101 | 800 | 20 | 150 |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | 20230202 | 900 | 25 | 180 |  |  |  |  |

If everything works, every empty column is filled by 365 days of data of a single parition.